# SimpleSearch modx

Tags: php, cms, modx

есть такая структура ресурсов в админке

```
Справочник лекарств(2)
- лекарство 1(3)
- лекарство 2(4)
- лекарство 3(5)

Справочник заболеваний(10)
 - заболевание 1(11)
 - заболевание 2(12)
 - заболевание 3(13)
```

как мне организовать поиск только в `Справочник лекарств`

пробовал так

```
[[!SimpleSearchForm? &landing=`102` &ids=`2` &tpl=`ssFormtTpl`]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Параметр `&ids=` надо указывать не в сниппете `SimpleSearchForm`, а в самом `SimpleSearch`.

```
[[!SimpleSearch? &ids=`2`]]
```

Comment: При выводе  ресурсе?